# How to crack several types of nuts in one batch?

Tags: nuts

I have a big bag of mixed nuts (hazelnuts, walnuts, pecans, Brazil nuts) in their shells that I want to crack open to enjoy later. I have tried to look up how to crack individual types of these nuts but they are all different. Can I just dump all the nuts in a barrel and soak them for a few hours until their shells are soft or will this ruin the nuts?

Comment: Why would you want to soak the nuts? Welcome, btw.

Comment: So that they'll crack more easily.

Comment: Put them in a sack and throw them against the ground.

Comment: I feel like that would break all the nuts and also make it hard to separate the broken shells from the nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really can't automate this. As you noted, each nut is cracked with a different technique and requires an individually independent amount of force.

Soaking the nuts won't accomplish anything desirable.